# oData v4 filtering by DateTime, string not converting to DateTime

Tags: .net, rest, api, asp.net-core, odata

My URI:

$filter=IsActive eq true and IsAutomated eq true and WebSite ne null
    and WebSite ne '' and LastUpdated le 2018-12-30T23:59:59.99Z

Controller:

```
    private readonly BrokerForgeContext _ctx;

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 20)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_ctx.Locations);
    }
```

Startup:

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<CashBidPrice>("CashBidPrices");
        builder.EntitySet<Location>("Locations");

        builder.EntityType<CashBidPrice>().Collection.Function("DeleteToday").Returns<bool>();

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Entity Model:

```
public partial class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int? Loc_Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    **[[ REMOVED FOR BREVITY ]]**
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get all Locations where the LastUpdate record is less than today, but having some major issues with filtering on the LastUpdated record. Everything else works great.

The error:

*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)
TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)*

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after tons of trial and error. The database column was a type DateTime. So I used this script to change it:

```
ALTER TABLE Locations
ADD LastUpdated2 datetimeoffset
GO

UPDATE Locations
SET LastUpdated2 = LastUpdated

ALTER TABLE Locations
DROP COLUMN LastUpdated
```

I renamed LastUpdated2 to LastUpdated manually using SSMS

Then I changed my entity model to be a DateTimeOffset Type

```
public DateTimeOffset? LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

My new URI filter is:

> ?$filter=IsActive eq true and IsAutomated eq true and WebSite ne null and WebSite ne '' and LastUpdated lt 2018-12-30T23:59:59.99Z